# Distinct count for entire dataset, grouped by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, count, distinct

I am dealing with a sales order table (ORDER) that looks roughly like this (updated 2018/12/20 to be closer to my actual data set):

```
SOID         SOLINEID         INVOICEDATE         SALESAMOUNT     AC
5            1                2018-11-30          100.00          01
5            2                2018-12-05          50.00           02
4            1                2018-12-12          25.00           17
3            1                2017-12-31          75.00           03
3            2                2018-01-03          25.00           05
2            1                2017-11-25          100.00          17
2            2                2017-11-27          35.00           03
1            1                2017-11-20          15.00           08
1            2                2018-03-15          30.00           17
1            3                2018-04-03          200.00          05
```

I'm able to calculate the average sales by SOID and SOLINEID:

```
SELECT SUM(SALESAMOUNT) / COUNT(DISTINCT SOID) AS 'Total Sales per Order ($)',
    SUM(SALESAMOUNT) / COUNT(SOLINEID) AS 'Total Sales per Line ($)'
FROM ORDER
```

This seems to provide a perfectly good answer, but I was then given an additional constraint, that this count be done by year and month. I thought I could simply add

```
GROUP BY YEAR(INVOICEDATE), MONTH(MONTH)
```

But this aggregates the SOID and then performs the COUNT(DISTINCT SOID). This becomes a problem with SOIDs that appears across multiple months, which is fairly common since we invoice upon shipment.

I want to get something like this:

```
Year     Month     Total Sales Per Order    Total Sales Per Line
2018     11        0.00
```

The sore thumb sticking out is that I need some way of defining in which month and year an SOID will be aggregated if it spans across multiple ones; for that purpose, I'd use MAX(INVOICEDATE).

From there, however, I'm just not sure how to tackle this. WITH? A subquery? Something else? I would appreciate any help, even if it's just pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the results, but the data sample does not have enuf rows to show Months...

```
SELECT
    mDateYYYY,
    mDateMM,
    SUM(SALESAMOUNT) / COUNT(DISTINCT t1.SOID) AS 'Total Sales per Order ($)',
    SUM(SALESAMOUNT) / COUNT(SOLINEID) AS 'Total Sales per Line ($)'
FROM DCORDER as t1
left join
    (Select
     SOID
     ,Year(max(INVOICEDATE)) as mDateYYYY
     ,Month(max(INVOICEDATE)) as mDateMM
From DCOrder 
Group By SOID
     ) as t2
 On t1.SOID = t2.SOID

 Group by mDateYYYY, mDateMM

mDateYYYY   mDateMM Total Sales per Order ($)   Total Sales per Line ($)
2018        12      87.50                       58.33
```

I have used new SQL still MAX(INVOICEDATE)(not above), with new 12/20 data, and excluded AC=17.

```
YYYY    MM  Total Sales per Order ($)   Total Sales per Line ($)
2017    11   35.00                       35.00
2018     1  100.00                       50.00
2018     4  215.00                      107.50
2018    12  150.00                       75.00
```

Comment: This query appears to give me the correct numbers when I don't have any constraints. Unfortunately, I simplified my problem, which did have two additional constraints.Essentially, I want to exclude an accounting code AC if it's 17, and I'd like to only look at 2017 and 2018. When I tried to add this WHERE clause before the "outer" group by, the total of the records did not correspond to a total from an ungrouped query. When I tried this inside the subquery, my numbers were still off.

Comment: At INVOICEDATE 2017/2018  or at  max(INVOICEDATE) 2017/2018 ?  Other than this and the AC=17, does the above solve the original problem?  If so, please click on the Check Mark above.  Also, we would need more test data to demonstrate this.  Make it easy for us.

Comment: I've updated my example to better reflect my data. These orders span multiple months and years, and I've added the AC column with several 17s.

Comment: Still need answer AND DATA for filter At INVOICEDATE 2017/2018 or at max(INVOICEDATE) 2017/2018 ??  What about 2016/2017/2018 do we chop off 2016 data but include the rest?  What about 2017/2018/2019 where max is 2019 do we drop the entire SOID?   (n.b.  the additional data looks good, and AC with 17 changes the results... more later)

Comment: I'm starting to see the issue. SUM(SALESAMOUNT) "should" be by calendar year, so we would group by INVOICEDATE. When we count SOIDs, I've been asking to roll these up to MAX(INVOICEDATE). We can't have both at the same time! Let's assume that I want to preserve the SUM(SALESAMOUNT) by INVOICEDATE; is there a clean way to make sure we're only counting each SOID once?

Comment: When an order has sales in two different months, the Dollars and the Count will occur in each of those months.  I would like to see Data  -AND- ExpectedResults for a few new SOID-s that speak to using INVOICEDATE and not Max(...)

Answer (score 1):

You should select Year() and month() for invocedate and group by

```
SELECT YEAR(INVOICEDATE) year
  , MONTH(INVOICEDATE) month
  , SUM(SALESAMOUNT) / COUNT(DISTINCT SOID) AS 'Total Sales per Order ($)'
  , SUM(SALESAMOUNT) / COUNT(SOLINEID) AS 'Total Sales per Line ($)'
FROM ORDER
GROUP BY YEAR(INVOICEDATE), MONTH(INVOICEDATE)
```

Comment: This query will double-count SOIDs with an INVOICEDATE that spans multiple months / years, as in my example data set. I only want each SOID to be counted for the month and year of the last INVOICEDATE.